# Why are my Django GAE requests returning "Property details must be a str or unicode instance, not a BoundField"

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-views

Why does the commented out code work, while the other code returns a BoundField error?  Shouldn't they be equivalent?

```
form = PostForm(request.POST)
post = Post(title = form['title'], details = form['details'])
#post = Post(title = request.POST['title'], details = request.POST['details'])
```

Also, I fear the title to this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent.

`form.data['title']` would be the equivalent of `request.POST['title']`

And if you want the processed data, try this:

```
form.is_valid()
form.cleaned_data['title']
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have seen it in the documentation, but I always get a little overwhelmed.